# I cant see if my list has repeated numbers in it

Tags: python, insertion

I'm trying to generate 20 random numbers in my list. Next I want to see if there are any repeated numbers in it.

I generated the random numbers. Next I did an insertion sort in order to arrange the list in a growing order. To see if I had any repeated numbers, I iterated over the list and if the previous number was equal to the next number, then my list had repeated numbers in it.

```
import random

random_array=[]

def array():
  for i in range(0,20):
    random_element=random.randint(1,35)
    random_array.append(random_element)
  return random_array
print(array())

# function to order the list
def insertion_sort():
  for i in range(1,len(random_array)):
    while i>0 and random_array[i-1]>random_array[i]:
      random_array[i-1],random_array[i]=random_array[i],random_array[i-1]
      i=i-1
  return random_array
print(insertion_sort())

def verification():
  for i in random_array:
    insertion_sort()
    if i-1==i:
      return True
    else:
      return False
print(verification())
```

My program always returns false independent of the generated list.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `if i-1==i:` ?

Comment: if the number in that position is equal to the number in the next position then there are repeated numbers

Comment: you are not iterating over the indexes, rather you are iterating over elements,fix up your for loop, also why are you calling insertion_sort in the loop?

Comment: what i wrote is the same as     for i in range(0,len(random_array):     if random_array(i-1)==random_array(i)....

Comment: random_array[i-1]*

Comment: @Luismaia1994, no it is not the same. i-1 does not refer to the element at the previous index, it resolves to the index value less 1.

Comment: so what do you sugest me to do

Comment: 1) `if random_array[i-1]==random_array[i]` is different from `if random_array(i-1)==random_array(i)` and is different from `if i-1==i`; 2) you don't need to run `insertion_sort()` in every iteration. You just need run `array()` and `insertion_sort()` once before `for` loop

Comment: also you are returning at the first mismatch you get, put your return outside for loop

Comment: Not to be rude, but there are quite a few issues with your verification algorithm. If your goal is just to check if you have any duplicates, use `if len(set(random_array)) == len(random_array): return True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with much shorter code using [itertools.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.Counter):

```
import random
from collections import Counter

# Generate a random array
random_array = [random.randint(1, 35) for _ in range(20)]


nums = [
    n  # A number
    for (n, count) in Counter(random_array).items()  # From countered items
    if count > 1  # If the count of this number is more than one
]
print(nums)
```

Comment: the goal also is to understand functions. I'm not interest in shorter codes yet. I know there are much easier ways to do the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Issues in your code:

- You are iterating on the elements and subtracting them and comparing, instead you should iterate on the indexes and use them to compare consecutive elements
- You are calling `insertion_sort()` within your for loop, I assume by mistake
- You want to break the for loop on the first match you found, and in the end return a boolean which tells if the match has happened or not

So your code will look like

```
def verification():
    #Flag to keep track of matches
    flag = False
    #Iterate over list via indexes
    for i in range(len(random_array)):
        #If consecutive elements match, set flag to true and break loop
        if random_array[i-1]==random_array[i]:
            flag = True
            break
    #Return flag value
    return flag
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here: If you don't care about the order, you can use `set` which is a data type that can only have unique elements. If you need to keep your original order of numbers, you need to use `OrderedDict` from `collections`

See this stack answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961393/11323304

Answer (score 0):

your loop in def verification(): is **exiting after first iteration because if else: return False (it's exiting)**

use simple flag:

```
import random

random_array=[]

def array():
  for i in range(0,20):
    random_element=random.randint(1,35)
    random_array.append(random_element)
  return random_array
print(array())

# function to order the list
def insertion_sort():
  for i in range(1,len(random_array)):
    while i>0 and random_array[i-1]>random_array[i]:
      random_array[i-1],random_array[i]=random_array[i],random_array[i-1]
      i=i-1
  return random_array
print(insertion_sort())

def verification():
  #for i in random_array:
  status = False # <----
  for i in range(len(random_array)-1): # <------
    insertion_sort()
    #if i-1==i:
    if random_array[i] == random_array[i+1]: # Iterate over list by indexes
      status = True
      break 
  return status
print(verification())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your verification function is wrong.  You are comparing the value of element i to the value of element i - 1, which is never going to be true. Try this:

```
insertion_sort()
for i in range(1,len(random_array - 1)):
    if random_arry[i] == random_array[i-1]:
        return True
return False  # If you get through every element without finding a match, return False
```